# Linear regression with quadratic constraints

Tags: regression, constraints

What methods are suggested to solve problems of the form $\min || {A} x - y ||_k$, subject to $x^T P x \leq c$, and/or $x^T Q x = d$?

Comment: Can you get away by solving the dual problem? Do you really mean $\|v\|_k=(\sum_i |v_i|^k)^{1/k}$?

Comment: Yes, I meant the norm as you defined it.

Comment: As it stands, the problem is non-convex, so there will be a duality gap. Solving the dual problem may not yield a desirable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of an inequality constraint only and semidefinite $P$, your problem is convex, and there may be better alternatives (CVX mentioned in the answer by Victor Liu, or the methods of arXiv:1009.2065 (which has at thre end a reference to a an implementation).

If $1<k<\infty$, you can use standard nonlinear programming software (see, e.g. http://neos-server.org/neos/ ); in case of an equality constraint or an inequality constraint with indefinite $P$, you are very unlikely to do better with other codes.

Otherwise, if $k=1$ or $k=\infty$, you need to introduce an extra variable $z$ for an upper bound on the objective, and minimize $z$ subject to your constraints and a bunch of linear constraints equvalent to $\|Ax-b\|_k\le z$,
and again use standard nonlinear programming software. Alternatively, you might use a nonsmooth optimization code; don't know what to recommend there, but a list of codes is at 
http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/software_l.html#nonsm

Answer (score 3):

Without the equality constraint, the problem is convex, and any standard interior point convex optimization package can be applied to solve this efficiently, such as the high level modeling software [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/).

With the equality constraint, the problem is no longer convex. However, you may approximate the solution by repeatedly solving a bunch of convex problems. One simple approach is to approximate the ellipsoid $x^TQx=d$ as a polyhedron and solve the optimization problem on all the facets of the polyhedron, then taking the best solution among all facets.

Comment: The problem is not necessarily convex without the equality constraint: $P$ must also be positive definite or at least positive semi-definite.

Comment: @AronAhmadia: For $c\ge 0$ and $P$ Hermitian, the negative subspace trivially fulfills the inequality, i.e., it can be projected out and the problem is convex.

Comment: @Deathbreath: No - the projection changes the problem to a different one!

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: How so? If $Q_-$ is the projector onto the subspace for which  $x^TPx\le0$, then $x^TQ_-PQ_-x \le c$ describes the same feasibility space and is convex.

Comment: The set defined by $x^TPx≤0$ is not a subspace, and the projector is ill-defined. - Try solving with your approach min |x-5| s.t. $x^2-y^2 \le 0$.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: Two erros have been made. a) I wrote the equation wrong: $x^T(I-Q_-)P(I-Q_-)x\le c$ is correct. b) You are misunderstanding me. The use of the word _subspace_ was intentional. This subspace is the largest for which $x^TPx\le 0$ holds. _All_ of that space is feasible and $Q_-$ is well defined. I essentially split $P$ by its positive and negative eigenvalues.

Comment: @Deathbreath: This doesn't settle the difficulties. In the 2D toy example I posed, if you set $y=0$ you get the wrong solution $x=0$ instead of the correct solution $x=5$ (and $|y|\ge 5$).